# Comparing Embedded Array Values and Getting Target Value

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am checking for equality on an array embedded within another array with the following code:

```
const equal = take("services", compare(
  take("history", compare(
    (a, b) => a._id === b._id
  ))
))(obj, obj2);
```

This is in comparing two documents that look something like this:

```
const obj = {
  _id: 1,
  services: [
    {
      _id: 23,
      service: "serviceOne",
      history: [
        {
          _id: 33,
          stage: "stageOne"
        }
      ]
    },
        {
      _id: 24,
      service: "serviceTwo",
      history: [
        {
          _id: 44,
          stage: "stageOne"
        }
      ]
    },
  ]
};

const obj2 = {
  _id: 1,
  services: [
    {
      _id: 23,
      service: "serviceOne",
      history: [
        {
          _id: 33,
          stage: "stageOne"
        }
      ]
    },
        {
      _id: 24,
      service: "serviceTwo",
      history: [
        {
          _id: 45,
          stage: "stageTwo"
        },
        {
          _id: 44,
          stage: "stageOne"
        }
      ]
    },
  ]
};
```

The above is working. When I run `console.log('equal: ', equal)` it logs `false`, because there is a difference within the level of the `history` array.

What I need to do now is dig out the value for "services.service" where the difference exists between the two documents. So far what I've tried only gets me the value for "history.stage":

```js
const compare = cb => (a, b) => a.length === b.length && a.every((el, i) => cb(el, b[i]));
const take = (key, cb) => (a, b) => cb(a[key], b[key]);
const obj = {
  _id: 1,
  services: [{
      _id: 23,
      service: "serviceOne",
      history: [{
        _id: 33,
        stage: "stageOne"
      }]
    },
    {
      _id: 24,
      service: "serviceTwo",
      history: [{
        _id: 44,
        stage: "stageOne"
      }]
    },
  ]
};

const obj2 = {
  _id: 1,
  services: [{
      _id: 23,
      service: "serviceOne",
      history: [{
        _id: 33,
        stage: "stageOne"
      }]
    },
    {
      _id: 24,
      service: "serviceTwo",
      history: [{
          _id: 45,
          stage: "stageTwo"
        },
        {
          _id: 44,
          stage: "stageOne"
        }
      ]
    },
  ]
};
const targetService = take("services", compare(
  take("history", compare(
    (a, b) => {
      a._id === b._id;
      console.log(a);
    }
  ))
))(obj, obj2);
console.log(targetService);
```

How would I get "services.service" in this case? Based on my documents here, I'd want to return `serviceTwo`, as it's the `history` array within that element that's changed.

Comment: Uh oh, if an answer ends up in another question, the answer was too complicated :)

Comment: @HereticMonkey, I think you need to look at the code again: these are functors.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep that functional pattern, you might want to add an `and` helper that allows you to perform multiple comparisons:

```
const compare = cb => (a, b) => a.length === b.length && a.every((el, i) => cb(el, b[i]));
const take = (key, cb) => (a, b) => cb(a[key], b[key]);
const and = (cb1, cb2) => (a, b) => cb1(a, b) && cb2(a, b);
const equals = (a, b) => a === b;

const equal = take("services", compare( 
  and(
   take("service", equals),
   take("history", compare(
     take("_id", equals)
   ))
  )
))(obj, obj2);
```

But it might be easier if you skip the functional programming thing and make it a bit easier to read:

```
 const historyEquals = (a, b) =>
   a._id === b._id;

 const serviceEquals = (a, b) => 
    a.service === b.service &&
    a.history.length === b.history.length &&
    a.history.every((el, i) => historyEquals(el, b.history[i]));

 const objEquals = (a, b) =>
    a.services.length === b.services.length &&
    a.services.every((el, i) => serviceEquals(el, b.services[i]));
```

Comment: This does look more readable to me. All 3 of these are booleans, correct? I also need a function that returns the string value of "services.service" on the "services" element that was changed.

Comment: @muirik yup, exactly. Then you want to `.find` instead of `.every`